# How to test a Promise callback inside a non-Promise function?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function that have promise function called inside. But itself doesn't return the promise.

```
const toBeTestedFunc = () => {
    const promise = promiseFunc()
                   .then(() => {})
                   .catch((error) => { errorHandler() });
}
```

How can I test if `errorHanlder()` is called? I wrote something like below, but it failed because test finished before promise callback has been executed.

```
const test = () => {
    toBeTestedFunc();
    expect(errorHandler).toBeCalled();
}
```

Comment: The fact you are finding this difficult to test is your code telling you that it needs to be restructured.

Comment: @Jared Smith So `toBeTestedFunc` should always return a Promise if it has promise used inside?

Comment: to the extent that it's possible, functions should do only one thing (and ideally return a value) or compositions of functions that all do only one thing. So yes, have it return the Promise.

Comment: Even if the `toBeTestedFunc` is synchronous? In my case, it's a function provided by the library which will be called at some specific time (`ComponentDidUpdate` in React-Native). I have no control of what it returns and I have to do something asynchronously here (by calling the `promiseFunc`). Is there a better way to make it more testable? BTW, how comes it violates the 'do only one thing' rule?

Comment: if toBeTestedFunc uses promises then it is not synchronous. If it is a function from a library then it should have tests at first place and you should  not need to test it. You should use what is called a `mock`.

Comment: @mpm Sorry I didn't make it clear. I overrided `toBeTestedFunc` to add these custom logic. The tests the library won't test the part I added, right? I used `jest.fn()` to mock the `promiseFunc()` and let it return a rejected promise. What I want to test is to make sure the `errorHandler` was called when the `promiseFunc()` rejected.

Comment: Well you need to spy on errorHandler then, if it is a function you wrote yourself

Comment: If it's *also* doing something synchronous, then it's doing two things, and that's a code smell. Refactor so that you have a function (easy to test) that does the sync stuff, another function (easy to test) that does the async stuff, and a third function that does nothing but call the first two (don't need to test).

Answer (score 1):

I realized this question has been posted few times. Seems like there is no good way to test in this case. The solution will be either:

- (Recommended) Return the promise in `toBeTestedFunc`, then test like this:

  ```
  const test = () => {
         toBeTestedFunc().then(() => {
             expect(errorHandler).toBeCalled();
         });    
  }
  ```

  Here is the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) for testing asynchronous functions.
- (Hacky solution) Mock the return value of `promiseFunc` to be a Object similar to `Promise`. So that test will wait the callback (`errorHandler`) to be executed. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727660/unit-testing-logic-inside-promise-callback?rq=1).

Thanks for @Jared Smith and @mpm's help :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way of waiting for the asynchronous operation, the only suggestion I have is to use https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/wait-for-expect. That will allow you to wait for your assertion to pass

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

As noted, the `expect` fails before the `Promise` callbacks have a chance to run.

### Solution

Give the `Promise` callbacks a chance to run before calling `expect`.

The ideal solution is, of course, to return the `Promise` from the function and `await` it directly.

For situations where that is not possible you can allow the `Promise` callbacks to execute by making the test function `async` and calling `await` on a resolved `Promise`.

This essentially queues the remainder of the test at the end of [the `PromiseJobs` queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) behind the `Promise` callbacks.

For cases where `Promise` callbacks queue additional `Promise` callbacks you can chain any number of `then()` calls to the resolved `Promise` to queue the rest of the test behind these additional callbacks.

---

Here is a working example:

```js
const errorHandler = jest.fn();
const promiseFunc = () => Promise.reject();

const toBeTestedFunc = () => {
  const promise = promiseFunc()
    .then(() => { })
    .catch((error) => { errorHandler() });
}

test('errorHandler called', async () => {   // make the test function async
  toBeTestedFunc();
  await Promise.resolve().then();   // allow the callbacks queued in PromiseJobs to run
  expect(errorHandler).toBeCalled();   // SUCCESS
});
```